# Иконка с прозрачным элементом

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть кнопки с разным цветом фона, в эти кнопки вставляется картинка с крестиком ("удалить"), область крестика должна быть прозрачной, т.е. цель такая чтобы крестик всегда был цвета фона кнопки.

Решение которое приходит в голову - это программно для каждой кнопки создавать LayerDrawable с крестиком нужного цвета.

А есть другой способ?

p.s. Использую векторные ресурсы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется очевидным что в вашем векторном ресурсе нет "дырки" в форме крестика, иначе бы никаких проблем и не было. Перерисуйте или скачайте новую иконку, если вдруг не поможет - прикрепите к вопросу сам xml иконки